# Fullcalendar timezone not correct in window.open (google calendar

Tags: timezone, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api, window.open

Since a while, I'm using the google calendar from fullcalendar.io
lately I noticed that my events are 'published' in my timezone (Europe/brussels) when I click on the event and when I'm not logged in to my google's account.

They are listed correct in the calenders month view as well as in the google calendar.

Side note: When I log in to my google account, the time of my event is correct in my event.

Here is a piece of my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    firstDay:1,
    weekNumbers:true,
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultView: 'month',

    eventClick: function(event) {
            // opens events in a popup window
            window.open(event.url, 'gcalevent', 'width=700,height=600');
            return false;
        },
```

Any help or suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure to fully understand your problem/question... When you are logged on your Google account, the events are published in your timezone (say 16:00) instead of the period defined in the event (say 14:00 because you're in UTC +2), is that it?
If so, you can force the timezone in FullCalendar.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the late notice.
When I'm logged on to my google account, my timezone is shown correctly. If not logged in, it shows my appointments in CEST, but I still want them to be in GMT+1 (Europe/brussels)

Comment: Hi,
I've found the issue. Somewhere in the code there was a reference to CEST time server. I changed it to GMT and now it works!